# What are the benefits of fermenting under pressure?

Tags: fermentation, process, pressure

I hear that some brewers ferment under pressure. What is the rationale/benefits of doing this?

Answer (score 13):

I am a very big fan of pressurized fermentation. The benefits I see, in rough order of the value I place on them:

**1) Pressurized ferments streamline my process tremendously.**
This is the big one. Once my wort is chilled, I transfer to a regular corny keg (just under 5 gallons). I keep the fermentation at 5 psi until it starts slowing down, and then I cap to my target carbonation level. For most beers, that's it. I cold crash, hook up to gas, and serve directly from the fermentor. That means less equipment to clean and less equipment to manage.

**2) Oxygenation is simple and consistent.**
To oxygenate my wort, I simply fill to the fill line and then bubble canned oxygen through the liquid diptube until I hit 4psi. With a liter and a half of headspace, by my math that puts me right at 15 ppm O2.

**3) The pressure keeps blow-off down**
I like fermenting in corny kegs because they are they cheapest stainless steel vessel I can find. However, they're a bit small. WIth a bit of pressure and a bit of fermcap, I'm able to ferment with them nearly full with only a very small amount of blow-off.

**4) I use less CO2.**
This likely isn't a big deal for most people, but where I live getting CO2 is a major pain. Since I started pressure fermenting, my CO2 cylinders have been lasting 3 times as long. That's two fewer trips to the welding store for every trip I still have to make.

**5) I can ferment warmer and thus don't need to cool as much.**
Because pressure inhibits ester and fusel formation, I ferment a few degrees warmer than I otherwise would to achieve similar results. I use thermoelectric cooling for space reasons, which is relatively energy intensive. This means I don't need to use as much.

For what it's worth, I'll thinking of switching to a pressure-capable conical at some point in the near future. This would change my process somewhat.

(I'll keep this list updated if I think of anything else.)

Comment: Leaving the beer on the yeast doesn't produce unwanted flavors eventually?  How do you handle blow-off and pressure release?

Comment: Eventually, probably. I bottle my big beers and other things I want to age significantly. For daily drinkers, though, I rarely keep a beer on tap longer than a couple of months.

Comment: I have a conical in the post, which takes up to 5psi IIRC. How did you come about your ppm of oxygen from the headspace?

Comment: People smarter than I helped me calculate a starting point in this thread (http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f128/oxygenation-under-pressure-306783/), and then I did a few experiments on my own with a dissolved oxygen meter. The headspace you have is the key factor, which might very well be different in a big conical.

Comment: On step 1, how do you figure out the fermentation is slowing down?