# What is the best yeast to ferment beer at higher temperatures?

Tags: yeast

With all the hot weather we have been having in my part of the world recently, what would be the best yeast to use for fermenting beer at (say) 20C or 22C. Obviously I am not making a lager - but aim to produce an IPA or a English bitter session beer. Does anyone have experience of or comment on higher temp fermentations?

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but people will probably ask for more details, such as target OG and FG. Also, what flavor character you wanna add to your beer.

Comment: I'm fermening my first beer right now so take that with a grain of salt but I've been reading a lot about how fermenting under pressure allows higher temperatures without producing off flavors I read other users report that Safale us-05 does fine to mid 70's F (in your range) without pressure and up to low 80's (28C) It might be worth seeing if you can ferment under pressure and keep your recipes in tact? See for some more info https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9750/what-are-the-benefits-of-fermenting-under-pressure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm eager to try this yeast. It's rumored to be as clean as california ale while fermenting in the 90's

http://www.omegayeast.com/portfolio/14158-2/

Comment: Wow, 16°C to 37°C is a wide range.  No need to cool the wort below 37 then...

Comment: Evil how available is omega yeast?

Comment: @JackScotti omega is based in Chicago, but I think the yeast species originated in Australia. I've not been able to find it locally in southern California yet. There's a good list on their homebrew link of where you can buy, many US locations and a few over seas.

Comment: the yeast is Norwegian ale strain.

Answer (score 2):

Well, 20°C to 22°C is not that high, if you look at this [link](http://beerandwinejournal.com/high-temp-yeast/) you will see that almost all of them can do it.

The highest temperature in the list is:  Wyeast 3724 (Belgian Saison) — 70-95 °F (21-35 °C)

Comment: I am not sure a Saison yeast would make a good IPA or English bitter!

Comment: No indeed, I was just pointing out the highest temperature tolerant yeast.  But pretty much any yeast will work at 22°C.   For an IPA, I suggest  a Safale-05 that works in the range of 15-22°C.